# Custom UICollectionView Cell Swipe Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Does anyone know the best way how to implement this animation or library with similar functionality? I assume that it can be done via affine transforms. But maybe somebody knows some examples.

[image: Discard animation]

Comment: It is tableview according to me. For this type of animation you can get github libraries.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I assume that this UICollectionView because of there is a big space between cells and it'll be easy to implement this via UICollectionView. Do you have links to these libraries?

Comment: I never seen this thing in `UICollectionView`. But for `UITableView` you can search on google -> **tableview swipe delete cell custom animation github**. If you didnt found anything related to your need then probably you need to make you own libraries.

Answer (score 0):

on tableView, you can use editActionForRowAt function(you can read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview) but because you are using a collection view you have to do it by yourself.

Add every cell a UIPanGestureRecognizer and make the animation according to the to the pan gesture.

like this:

```
func setupSwipeGesture() {
        swipeGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(swiped(_:)))
        swipeGesture.delegate = self

        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }

func swiped(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
       let xDistance:CGFloat = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self).x
       // do your animation
}
```